# Angular 4.3 HttpClient: catch webapi error response body

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, error-handling, angular-http, bad-request

I'm trying to handle errors returned by my .NET Core WebApi from an Angular 4.3 service using the new `HttpClientModule`.

I'm making the http request as follows:

```ts
postUser(model: IPostUser): Observable<IUser> {
    return this.http.post<IUser>(this.originUrl + '/api/registry', model)
        .catch((reason: any) => this.handleError(reason));
}
```

the `handleError` method is:

```ts
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse | any): ErrorObservable {
    // in a real world app, we might use a remote logging infrastructure
    let errStatus: string;
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        try {
            const body: any = error.error || error;
            const err: string = body.message || JSON.stringify(body);
            errStatus = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''}`;
            errMsg = `${err}`;

            if (error.status === 0) {
                errMsg = 'Si é verificato un errore. Si prega di riprovare più tardi.';
            } else if (error.status === HttpStatusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED || error.status === HttpStatusCodes.FORBIDDEN) {
                errMsg = 'Non hai effettuato l\'accesso.';
            }
        } catch (ex) {
            errMsg = 'Si é verificato un errore. Si prega di riprovare più tardi.';
        }
    } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errStatus + ': ' + errMsg);
    this.toastrService.error(errMsg, 'Errore');
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

And the WebApi controller action makes the following security checks:

```csharp
var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.Id);
if (user == null)
    return NotFound("Utente non trovato.");

if ((await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName)) != null)
    return BadRequest("Esite già un utente con questo Username.");
else if ((await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email)) != null)
    return BadRequest("Esite già un utente con questa Email.");
else if ((await _userManager.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.TaxCode == model.TaxCode)) != null)
    return BadRequest("Esite già un utente con questo Codice Fiscale.");
```

So depending on what user try to post to the server, the server throw a NotFound or BadRequest respose with a body that is an object containing a message.

A bad call to that WebApi action cause this error:

> undefined: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

I've tried to use an *HttpInterceptor* to catch the error response body:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor(private router: Router) { }

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next.handle(req).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            // do stuff with response if you want
        }
    }).catch((error: any) => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
            let x = error;
            if (error.status === HttpStatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST || error.status === HttpStatusCodes.NOT_FOUND) {
                return Observable.throw(error);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

}

But also with the interceptor the error is still the same anche the `catch` method right after the `post` call in the Angular service was called with the `TypeError` exception shown above rather than my custom error object.

Any solution? How can I catch a BadRequest/NotFound error response from the server and get the error response body correctly?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I've another interceptor that returns an `Observable.throw(..)` only for `401` and `403` error responses. Making it always return the exception solves the problem.